# Does it protect SSD by putting Chrome/IE cache into ramdisk?

Tags: ssd, ramdisk

I have bought a SSD, alloc 1G memory for ramdisk to save temp file of Chrome/IE. Does it reduce the i/o of SSD and enlarge the lifetime of SSD?

Answer (score 3):

If data is saved to the RAM disk and not to the SSD: Yes.
(Regardless of what data it is).

However:

1. The cache is used for a reason. If you just put then on a RAM disk without extra actions you will always start with an empty cache. This can make surfing slower because the browser bow has to fetch data which it otherwise might have found in the local cache.
   (I specifically mention without extra actions since there is at least on RAMdisk package out there which allows you to pre-load data on creating, and saves this data on shutdown).
2. There seem to be a lot of similar questions here on S.U. All based on 'how do a minimise wear and tear on my SSD.' All of these seem to assume that a SSD has a very limited lifespan. This is not true. A modern SSD has a limited lifespan, but most people  will not reach that limit with normal usage.
   (Where normal usage is not maxing writes for 10 continious years. But heavy usage for 5-6 years (about the normal period until a computer is replaced) should not be a problem.)

Comment: You must be joking about the 5-6 years.

Comment: Most mom and pop desktops last 5 to 10 years. Just because we 'heavy users' tend to replace a computer more often does not change the average all that much.

Comment: An average desktop here in Poland lasts ~10 years. And yes, this applies equally to “power users”.

Comment: Then I guess I am spoiled. I live mostly a crowd of friends working in IT. A new computer usually lasts 2 years before it gets replaced. Computers around non-IT acquaintances seem to last 5-6 years here (NL based)